# Redirect localhost to https nginx magento

Tags: http, nginx, https, localhost, magento-1.9

I am running a magento website on my localhost and want to redirect it to https so that service workers can get registered. my conf file is

```
upstream php-handler {
     server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
 }

 server {
     listen 80;
     listen              *:443 ssl;

     server_name         mytestsite.com;

     ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/wildcard.chained.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/somekey.key;

     return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

     # Path to the root of your installation
     root /home/webstack/magento;

     index index.php;
     error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
     error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

     location = /robots.txt {
         allow all;
         log_not_found off;
         access_log off;
     }

     location ~ ^/(?:\.htaccess|data|config|db_structure\.xml|README) {
             #deny all;
     }

     location / {
             # The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger
             rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
             rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

             rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
             rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

             rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

             #try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
     }


     location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
             include fastcgi_params;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
             #fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
             fastcgi_pass php-handler;
     }

     # Optional: set long EXPIRES header on static assets
     location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
             expires 30d;
             # Optional: Don't log access to assets
             access_log off;
     }

}
```

when i restart the nginx server and type the address https://mytestsite.com it says

**The mytestsite.com page isn’t working
mytestsite.com redirected you too many times.**

I've tried clearing the cache and cookies but its still the same.

can anyone tell me what is wrong with the conf file? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line

`return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;`

and set unsecure and secure links on magento admin panel(System>Configuration>Web)

```
Base URL            = https://mytestsite.com
Base Link URL       = https://mytestsite.com
Base Skin URL       = https://mytestsite.com
Base Media URL      = https://mytestsite.com
Base JavaScript URL = https://mytestsite.com
```

Comment: Thanks....got it working though....had found a way out...but i appreciate your help.